# Increment sequential numbers in 4 different cells after printing

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, printing

I created a 1/4 letter size receipt and copied it 4 times in a single worksheet (to save papers) and want it to be printed continuously from 001 to 100. Each receipt should have a unique serial number 001,002...100..

How can I put sequential numbers in 4 different cells, say A1,C1,E1,and G1 are my cells with numbers 001,002,003,004, and increase each number after each print?

I also need the ability to specify the starting number.

I found this in a web so maybe it could be a start:

```
Sub IncrementPrint()

    Dim xCount As Variant
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
LInput:
    xCount = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of copies you want to print:", "Title")
    If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xCount)) Or (xCount < 1) Then
        MsgBox "error entered, please enter again", vbInformation, "Title"
        GoTo LInput
    Else
        xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For I = 1 To xCount
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = " Company-00" & I
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").ClearContents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's that do for you? Does it work? Where does it break? (Hint, that `GoTo LInput` isn't coding practice, but it can still be functional.)

Comment: it printed 1 number per page but i needed a function that works for 4 sequential numbers on each page. For example: the first print page has 001, 002, 003, and 004 and then 2nd print would appear 005,006,007,008 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub IncrementPrint()
    Dim resp As Variant, scr As Boolean, i As Long, j As Long

On Error Resume Next
    resp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the number of copies to print:", _
                                Title:="Select Total Print Copies", Type:=1)
On Error GoTo 0

    If resp = False Then Exit Sub
    If resp < 1 Or resp > 100 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid number: " & resp & " (Enter 1 to 100)", vbExclamation, "Try Again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    scr = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To resp
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value2 = " Company-00" & i + 0 + j
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value2 = " Company-00" & i + 1 + j
        ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value2 = " Company-00" & i + 2 + j
        ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Value2 = " Company-00" & i + 3 + j
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        j = j + 3
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1,C1,E1,G1").ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = scr
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks paul, it worked. But what if i want to start from a number, Not 1 or 0.. let say i stopped from 052 and i would like to print remaining serial number starting 053? sorry, i am very new at this..

Comment: Another thing, I tried to run this code a few times to check if its working, i noticed that print twice each page. I don't know why it is happening. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is (don't have a printer so to run the code I commented out the print line) but I'm suspecting something, and I made a couple of changes. Please try again and if it's not fixed, use the old code to see if it does the same. Let me know how it works out

Comment: thanks again paul, the code ran smoothly. Can I know what the problem on the first code maybe?

Comment: Glad it works! The first code only incremented the label in cell A1. I added the other 3 cells, and also made sure that the label increments for all of them in each iteration (using the new variable `j`). I also limited the user response to 100 copies in case their keyboard gets stuck on a number :)